# ANTLR : No viable alternative error '{"type"'

Tags: javascript, java, antlr, antlr4

I know there are a lot of this questions and we've been going through them all but we can't seem to find a solution that fits our needs.

We wrote a simple grammar for a javascript to Java converter, the lexer and the parser and we can't get it to consume the first token of our input file correctly.

Here's the grammar:

```
lexer grammar JS2JAVALexer;

STRING
   : '"' (ESC | ~ ["\\])* '"'
   ;
fragment ESC
   : '\\' (["\\/bfnrt] | UNICODE)
   ;
fragment UNICODE
   : 'u' HEX HEX HEX HEX
   ;
fragment HEX
   : [0-9a-fA-F]
   ;
NUMBER
   : '-'? INT '.' [0-9] + EXP? | '-'? INT EXP | '-'? INT
   ;
fragment INT
   : '0' | [1-9] [0-9]*
   ;
// no leading zeros
fragment EXP
   : [Ee] [+\-]? INT
   ;
// \- since - means "range" inside [...]
WS
   : [ \t\n\r] + -> skip
   ;

OPENPAR : '(' ;
CLOSEPAR : ')' ;
OPENBRACES : '{' ;
CLOSEBRACES : '}' ;
OPENBRACKETS : '[' ;
CLOSEBRACKETS : ']' ;
TWOPOINTS : ':' ;
QUOTATION_MARK : '"';
COMMA : ',' ;
TRUE : 'true';

FALSE : 'false';
NULL : 'null' ;

TYPE : 'type';
SOURCETYPE : '"sourceType"';
BODY : '"body"';
```

After running it we get the error "line 2:4 no viable alternative at input '{"type"'

This is our input file:

```
{
    "type": "Program",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "FunctionDeclaration",
            "id": {
                "type": "Identifier",
                "name": "name"
            },
            "params": [
                {
                    "type": "Identifier",
                    "name": "arg1"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Identifier",
                    "name": "arg2"
                }
            ],
            "defaults": [],
            "body": {
                "type": "BlockStatement",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "VariableDeclaration",
                        "declarations": [
                            {
                                "type": "VariableDeclarator",
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "Identifier",
                                    "name": "x"
                                },
                                "init": {
                                    "type": "Literal",
                                    "value": 1,
                                    "raw": "1"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "kind": "var"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "VariableDeclaration",
                        "declarations": [
                            {
                                "type": "VariableDeclarator",
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "Identifier",
                                    "name": "y"
                                },
                                "init": {
                                    "type": "Literal",
                                    "value": 2,
                                    "raw": "2"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "kind": "var"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ReturnStatement",
                        "argument": {
                            "type": "BinaryExpression",
                            "operator": "+",
                            "left": {
                                "type": "Identifier",
                                "name": "x"
                            },
                            "right": {
                                "type": "Identifier",
                                "name": "y"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "generator": false,
            "expression": false
        }
    ],
    "sourceType": "script"
}
```

Parser's code:

```
parser grammar JS2JAVAParser;

options {
    tokenVocab = JS2JAVALexer;
}

json
   : object
   | array
   ;

object
   : OPENBRACES pair (COMMA pair)* CLOSEBRACES
   | OPENBRACES CLOSEBRACES
   ;

left_operand 
    : QUOTATION_MARK left_name QUOTATION_MARK
    ;

left_name 
    : TYPE 
    | BODY 
    | SOURCETYPE
    | DECLARATIONS
    | ID
    | INIT
    | OPERATOR
    | LEFT
    | RIGHT
    | VALUE
    | RAW
    | KIND
    ;

pair
   : left_operand TWOPOINTS value
   ;

array
   : OPENBRACKETS value (COMMA value)* CLOSEBRACKETS
   | OPENBRACKETS CLOSEBRACKETS
   ;

value
   : QUOTATION_MARK value_name QUOTATION_MARK
   | object
   | array
   | TRUE
   | FALSE
   | NULL
   | STRING
   | IDENTIFIER
   | LITERAL
   | VAR
   | STRING
   ;

value_name 
    : SCRIPT
    | PROGRAM
    ;
```

Sorry for such a long and repetitive question but we're running out of ideas. Thank you in advance for your patience guys.

Comment: Check grammer and build AST in AnltWorks. AST will help you finding error.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Will do, thank you! But do you know what the exact error is? We are running a bit low on time. Also does AntlrWorks work on eclipse?

Comment: I think { braces are having problem in STRING

Comment: We are looking into it. I'm also trying to test it in AntlrWorks.
As far as the error goes what do you think it may be wrong? @ParthTrivedi
How can it unify "{" with STRING if we make sure that STRING get a ' " ' char first...

Comment: Is this for antlr4 or antlr3? These two are quite different, so please remove one tag.

Comment: @cantSleepNow done! thank you for the tip

Comment: @CarlosPereira no problem ;) Could you please paste also the parser grammar? This error seems like it's from parser rules...

Comment: @cantSleepNow Posted the parser's code above. Thank you for your time man.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your top level parser rule "type" is recognized as STRING token. Actually, seems that everything that could be STRING or something else will be recognized as STRING. So basically you need to resolve the lexer ambiguity. By rewriting lexer rules, or potentially using lexer modes.

Also at least as a reference, there is [this JSON grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/json/JSON.g4) on ANTLR's github repo.